# html5 canvas game not working properly in android avd

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, android-virtual-device

I have developed a html5 canvas game(Arkanoid game) using javascript. it is working fine in ff n crome browsers. Later i have downloaded an app from phonegap.com and using eclipse and android sdk i have run the game in android virtual device, but the problem is the game is working very very slow and if i click on the canvas element to call mousedown event the entire canvas is being selecting...

what might b the problem??

is there any other way to convert that html5 page to android .apk file???

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator is much, much slower than an actual device. Try using an actual android phone for testing, it would really help.

Comment: @ Dhaivat: I have hosted the game in my website and tried to open it in android phone browser,even though same problem.